# Script to copy multiple files to multiple directories

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a directory containing many files:

```
abc.txt
def.txt
ghi.txt
   etc.
```

I have written a script which creates a new directory based on the name of each file (Directories abc, def, ghi etc.).

Now I want to copy file abc.txt into directory abc, file def.txt into directory def and so on.

I'm trying to do this using shutil but my script doesn't work.

```
import os, glob, shutil

myfiles = glob.glob("/users/source_directory/*.*")
for f in myfiles:
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
    destination = (os.path.join('/users/destination_directory/',file_name))
    shutil.copy(f, (os.path.join(destination,file_name)))
```

This produces a copy of the source file minus its file extension in the source directory. Any suggestions for how to get it to work as intended?

Comment: Make the directory first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your file_name variable does not contain only the file name but the whole absolute path of the file. This means that the os.path.join command for your destination variable overrides the /users/destination_directory path by /users/source_directory.

Second, you have to create the new directories.

Third, I added also the file extension for the copy process.

The following code is doing your job.

```py
import os, glob, shutil

myfiles = glob.glob("/users/source_directory/*.*")
for f in myfiles:
    file_path, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    destination = os.path.join('/users/destination_directory/',file_name)
    os.mkdir(destination)
    shutil.copy(f, (os.path.join(destination,file_name+file_extension)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. Your script does exactly what I hoped it would.